Mongo Shell prompts for "it" when I want all results
How can I run a query that I know will return a large dataset without having to type "it" to see all result and without modifying the query itself?
I want to redirect all output to a file, so I'm doing the following:
mongosh < my.query > my.result

The last line in the result file is 'Type "it" for more', so I'm clearly not getting all results.
The query is:
db.coll.find({device_type: "XYZ"},{_id: 1,expire_date:1});

When I add .toArray() to the query, the file ends with "... 36 more items ]"

Please post your query. The .find() method uses pagination. .toArray() should return everything. Thats why you should post a Minimal, Reproducible Example (Your query). Also please complete the tour and read How do I ask a good question?

Does this answer your question? How to print out more than 20 items (documents) in MongoDB's shell?

@ray Yes, that's one way to solve the problem. The solution that I prefer is one that doesn't make me rewrite my queries, i.e. to use the setting DBQuery.shellBatchSize.

@ManFromuncle That is exactly what the accepted answer in the link do

@ray The solution you pointed out is a reasonable alternative, but it doesn't satisfy my desire to not modify the query. So both solutions are acceptable, but I prefer to set the shellBatchSize parameter.

I found that I can put this statement ahead of the query:
DBQuery.shellBatchSize=1000;

Then I know I'll get at least 1000 docs. Still not ideal, because I may not know how many docs are in the result set. But it's gotten me past my current issue.
